# Setting generic launch/run configuration in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

When I select a class and choose Run as,
how can have eclipse give sub menu options such as Java application, Android application?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, it's up to the plugin-contributor to set those actions. They are called lanuch-configuration-shortcuts, and unless it was not added in the plugin contribution, it will not be there.
Also, lunch shortcuts appear where are configured to appear, so if your current file (content-type) does not match the configuration rule, it will not appear in the Run-As.